# WebComponentsJS with IE10

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am trying to use `webcomponentsjs` from http://webcomponents.org/.  Unfortunately, information on this topic and this website is extremely messy and difficult to ascertain.  The browser support matrix on the website says no IE support.  However the matrix on the GitHub says it has IE support, but two of the four categories are "flaky" (and they don't mention what that means): https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs

The `bower` version of this library doesn't work at all for me in any browser due to a reported bug (https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/180).  The issue was fixed, but it didn't seem to have made it into the new release.  So I just used the `webcomponents.js` file from the master branch and it now works in modern web browsers such as Chrome and Firefox.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work at all for IE10 (simply renders nothing, but there are no errors).  I then tried the example web component (http://webcomponents.org/hello-world-element/), and that also does not render in IE.

Looking at the GitHub page, it seems to indicate that this *might*, at least partially, work in IE10.  My point is, the wording across this project is extremely vague and contradictory.

**That leads me to my question:**  Do web components, with the `webcomponents.js` polyfill, work in IE10?  Specifically, *what* doesn't work in IE10?  I know that *some* things do, but as made evident by the hell-world app, not everything does.

Comment: Try https://beta.webcomponents.org/ and https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/

Comment: Everything I have read says that IE10 will not work with the Polyfill. If you manage to get it to work, please let us know. But I think you have to use IE11.

Answer (score 0):

Webcomponents on its vainilla form are really tricky, specially if you want to run them on environments such as IE 10. What I would try (and has been the solution for me, although, a few months back, don't know if it is still viable) is to install a prior version of the `webcomponents.js` script, for example:

`bower install --save webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^0.7.0`

`webcomponents.js` just released its 2.1.2 version. Its goal is no longer to support IE10, but to ensure a fast and reliable experience to all major, modern browsers. At some point in the way, though, its goal was indeed, to support IE10. So, installing an older version, might do the trick.

Just keep in mind: that would be a downgrade to the entire script.

If you are new to webcomponents world, I get that you want to run a vainilla component before experimenting with a library such as Polymer, for example. But what you are doing here is an overcomplication: Choose between running a vainilla component, or running a component in IE10. But also, the most important thing about learning a new technology is to be able to use it and create products with it. So maybe using Polymer to create some apps until you are comfortable writing web components would be great, after than, then lets dive into edge cases and vainilla stuff.

If you are experienced with webcomponents and you are just running into this problem, I hope the approach of an older script version helps you.